# pandoc - how to generate hugo-like section page?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc, hugo

In hugo a *section* page is file `_index.md` and by default this page is a type of list, ie. it would have URL links to other files/pages in same directory.

How would I do that with `pandoc`. Let's image I have a directory named `fruits` and with a file named `_index.md` which would have some content in markdown. Then there would be multiple markdown files, each corresponding to a fruit type - subpages in the same directory.

How to get list of all markdown files except `_index.md` in the directory, title from each markdown file's frontmatter, and how to construct a code being merged into section's `_index.md`?

Comment: You could try to write a Lua filter which finds the files, reads theirs contents, and then use that information to compose the links. Not super fast, but doable.